# Why is my touch event frequency slower on iOS 4.0?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4

I'm writing a finger sketch type app and had the app working great on iOS 3.0. However, running the app under iOS 4.0 or greater is causing problems. Specifically, I am receiving touch events to my app approximately 5x slower on the new OS than on the old. This obviously causes my app to draw poorly because I'm capturing 5x less data points to draw between.

Any ideas on how to speed up touch event frequency on iOS4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain graphics operations take a lot longer in iOS4.x than in 3.x (somewhere between 2X to 10X slower).  The longer graphics execution times could be blocking the main UI thread, and not leaving enough time for the main thread run loop to handle user (touch) events.

Profile your drawRect code and see if it's now taking longer that one refresh rate tick time.  If so, try speeding up or breaking up your graphics renders, or try a lower frame rate, and see if any of that helps.

Comment: I'm fairly new at drawing code so here is my general strategy. I'm subclassing UIView. In the touches moved method, I have an array that stores points that need to be drawn to the view. I've also created a timer with interval 0.03 that when fired, calls setNeedsDisplay. I declared the timer as follows in viewDidLoad:  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

Comment: Is this a correct approach? Or am I missing something with the way threads are running here. Can I draw on a seperate thread so it doesn't block the main thread (so I can receive more touch events)?

Comment: Before you can determine whether your timer value is correct, you need to find out how much time your drawRect code takes.  Certain types of CG drawing are thread safe, but not UI drawing code in general.

Comment: @aloo - It sounds like you've been running into performance problems for a while in your drawing code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123306/optimizing-a-drawing-with-finger-touches-application-for-iphone-sdk , so you might want to look at flattening your drawing into a bitmap at regular intervals to avoid some of these slowdowns.  As always, profile with Instruments to determine the exact hotspots.

Comment: yes its true! I've gone through many iterations of it and founds something that worked on all pre-iphone4's. As you suggest, I already draw onto a separate layer at regular intervals but had to slow down this interval for the iPhone 4.

Comment: @Brad - I watched your performance tuning videos on itunes, very well done!

Answer (score 1):

You should profile your code with Shark to see where the bottleneck is.  What is probably happening is some of your code that executes on the main thread (most likely something that runs in response to a touch) is taking longer than expected which is preventing your app from receiving touch events

Comment: Does drawRect run in the main loop?

Answer (score -1):

Block the main thread less.